# Navigation styling - selecting child li only

Tags: asp.net, css, navigation, sitefinity

I'm building a LHN in Sitefinity and ran into an issue styling it. When a page is set as the active page, it gets the sfsel class. Unfortunately, it also applies it to the parent page when a subpage is active. I need to get the styling so when a subpage is active, only that list item is highlighted, but when only the parent "About" page is active, it still gets highlighted.

http://jsfiddle.net/4NnaZ/1/

```
<div class="sfNavWrp sfNavTreeviewWrp leftnav">
<div class="k-widget k-treeview" tabindex="0" role="tree" aria-activedescendant="C001_ctl00_ctl00_navigationUl_tv_active">
    <ul class="sfNavTreeview sfNavList k-group k-treeview-lines" id="C001_ctl00_ctl00_navigationUl" data-role="treeview">
        <li class="k-item k-first k-last" data-uid="ceac0efa-1b50-46c7-a351-945f05a6eb87" role="treeitem" data-expanded="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <div class="k-top k-bot"><span class="k-icon k-minus"></span><a class="sfSel k-in" href="../about">About</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="C001_ctl00_ctl00_ctl03_ctl00_childNodesContainer" class="k-group" style="display: block;">
                <li class="k-item" data-uid="3b1f4e90-1945-4c93-a770-43787527d7bf" role="treeitem" id="C001_ctl00_ctl00_navigationUl_tv_active">
                    <div class="k-top"><a class="sfSel k-in k-state-focused" href="locations">Locations</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="k-item" data-uid="48d48d44-55ee-4bf7-9fcd-20380c18b991" role="treeitem">
                    <div class="k-mid"><a href="careers" class="k-in">Careers</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="k-item" data-uid="267e4a18-8489-45c2-bef3-1efcba63916f" role="treeitem">
                    <div class="k-mid"><a href="producer-board" class="k-in">Producer Board</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="k-item k-last" data-uid="d75d7989-3815-49b3-856c-c4d24dcd5dc8" role="treeitem">
                    <div class="k-bot"><a href="contact-information" class="k-in">Contact Information</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what script do you use to set sfSel class ? cause CSS won't help really . this :  div > ul >li > div > a.sfSel {
    background-color: #ffcd00;
} would, but what if it is another link that is really active page ?looks to me like a bug script , not a CSS issue

Comment: It's built into Sitefinity. The current page and its parent both get the sfsel class.

Comment: JavaScript could be the solution to delete the class from parent,but  is there no way to fix this funny behavior (2 different links set as active page), i guess you are not the first one to run into this.

Answer (score 0):

isn't `k-state-focused` the class you should use to highlihgt only current link/page ?

I believe this is a jQuery script producing this classname.

You can modify your code to set a class for that purpose , http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/general-discussions-/highlight-current-page